# How to configure a plugin to depend on a specific version of gradle?

Tags: gradle

I am writing a set of Gradle plugins, but I want to control the specific versions of groovy and gradle that are used.

I don't want the plugins to depend on whatever versions of Gradle/Groovy are installed, like the following would do:

```
dependencies {
  compile localGroovy()
  compile gradleApi()
}
```

Another reason I don't want to use the local method - when you use a proper dependency specification, Gradle then knows about the source code for those libs and the IDE plugins can hookup the source automatically.

Below are the relevant sections of my build script:

```
allprojects { Project iProject ->
  apply plugin: 'idea'
  apply plugin: 'maven'

  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}

subprojects { Project iProject ->
  apply plugin: 'groovy'

  dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.2'
  }

}

project(':eclipsei2g') {
  group = 'eclipsei2g'
  version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

  dependencies {
    compile 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.0'
  }
}

project(':g2idea13') {
  group = 'g2idea13'
  version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

  dependencies {
    compile 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.0'
    compile 'org.gradle-plugins:gradle-ide:2.0'
  }
}
```

When I run this I get an error resolving the gradle-ide dependency:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':g2idea13:compile'.
  > Could not find org.gradle:gradle-ide:2.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
  http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/gradle/gradle-ide/2.0/gradle-ide-2.0.pom
http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/gradle/gradle-ide/2.0/gradle-ide-2.0.jar
Required by:
g2idea13:g2idea13:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

There doesn't seem to be anything on the jcenter repository since 0.9 for the plugins stuff.
I also tried 'org.gradle:gradle-ide:2.0'.

Is this even how I should be doing this?  Is there another way to specify a specific gradle version?  Am I just using the wrong repository?  I couldn't even get gradle-core to resolve on mavenCentral().  Is there an official Gradle repository somewhere that I should be using?

Comment: If you use gradle wrapper for your plugin than the version of Gradle and Groovy is locked. Isn't that sufficient for you?

Comment: Not really.  It doesn't fix the library source thing and doesn't express the intent of the build script.  I don't mind building my plugin with the latest Gradle - but I want the plugin itself to be usable on older versions of Gradle.  Also seems wasteful to pull in the entire gradle API surface area when all I really need is gradle-core and gradle-ide (makes for a much bigger library dependency list in the IDE).

Comment: Just realised that specifying the dependencies for the plugin forces any script that uses the plugin to resolve that dependency as well (i.e. must add jcenter() or similar to the buildscript repositories section).  So it's just an all around bad idea, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gradleApi()` is the way to go. There isn't currently a public list of dependencies for Gradle plugins.